# Что за тип данных uintptr_t в языке C?

Tags: c

Что за тип данных `uintptr_t` в `Си`? Зачем он нужен и для чего используется?

Comment: [uintptr_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-the-uintptr-t-data-type).

Comment: unitptr_t или uintptr_t?

Comment: И него можно сделать [XOR list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list).

Answer (score 6):

> **7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers**
> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to **void** can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to **void** , and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
> `intptr_t`
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to **void** can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to **void** , and the result willcompare equal to the original pointer:
> `uintptr_t`
>
> These types are optional.

Этот без знаковый целочисленный тип, который способен принять указатель и не потерять значение. То-есть при 64-битных процессорах, этот тип будет иметь размерность 64 бита, а в 32-битных - 32 бита.
Предназначен для удобной работы с указателями в целочисленной форме.
Эти типы опциональны и компиляторы не обязаны его предоставлять.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdint.h>
# include <inttypes.h>
int main(){
  double x ;
  uintptr_t p = ( uintptr_t ) & x ;
  printf("sizeof(p)=%zu\n",sizeof(p));
  printf("p=%" PRIxPTR "\n",p);
  ++ p;
  printf("p=%" PRIxPTR "\n",p);
}

sizeof(p)=8
p=7ffe33df1b0c
p=7ffe33df1b0d
```

инкремент прибавляет **один**, а в случае с указателем на тип `double` прибавилось бы 8. Так-же у указателей не предусмотрены битовые операции `|` `&` `^` `~` `<<` `>>`. А у таких целочисленных типов можно.
Из недостатков можно отметить, что теряются классификаторы типов, таких-как **const**, **volatile**, **_Atomic** и **restrict**.

```
double const volatile _Atomic x ;
void const volatile _Atomic * restrict  vp = & x;
uintptr_t pvp = vp ;
```

Comment: Спецификаторы преобразования могут не соответствовать типам передаваемых аргументов, следовательно поведение программы может быть не определено. Нужны `"%zu"` и `"%" PRIxPTR` для типов `size_t` и `uintptr_t` соответственно.

Comment: @wololo про `%zu` правильно, но `PTIxPTR` ещё не использовал, обычно `%p` всегда хватало